# How to bundle a library with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, umd

I want to create a frontend library.
Therefore I want to use webpack. I especially like the css and image loader.
However I can only require non-JS files if I am using webpack.
Because I am building a library, I cannot garanty that the user of my library will too.

Is there I way to bundle everything into a UMD module to publish it?
I tried using multiple entry points, however I cannot require the module then.

Comment: Maybe i miss something, do you mean that you want to publish your library  package to npm, and users will `import` it? So why "I can only require non-JS files if I am using webpack"? Could you give an example? And about "I tried using multiple entry points" Have you considered the possibility that you don't need `webpack` - only `babel` will be enough?

Comment: Yes I have considered only using babel.
However if I require("./something.css") and don't use webpack in a project where I require("my-library"). If I run this it will not work.

Comment: So you want to create a library which would be used without webpack? Ok. Did you tried it with single entry point?

Comment: yes, but that's basically my question how to do that.

Comment: Have you seen this examples [webpack-library-example](https://github.com/kalcifer/webpack-library-example/tree/master/examples)? Will it solve your question?

Comment: No, but it doesn't use a loader.
E.g. require("./somethind.css").
How can I garanty that the css is loaded correctly?

Comment: Hi Arwed Mett! Is it still actual for you? I just played with creating 'webpack` packages and finally I build library which incapsulates image and css in one JS file. It's possible to import it and use without `webpack` or `babel`. I've published this example to Github. Could you check it and tell me is it what you asked about? https://github.com/UsulPro/libpack

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: Check https://github.com/atte-backman/ts-library-boilerplate/blob/master/src/app/services/postService.ts

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can find good guide for creating libraries in Webpack 2.0 [documentation site](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/). That's why I use ver 2 syntax in `webpack.config.js` for this example.

Here is a [Github repo](https://github.com/UsulPro/libpack) with an example library.

It builds all files from `src/` (`js`, `png` and `css`) into one JS bundle which could be simply required as an `umd` module.

for that we need to specify the follow settings in `webpack.config.js`:

```
output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: 'libpack.js',
    library: 'libpack',
    libraryTarget:'umd'
},
```

and `package.json` should have:

```
"main": "dist/libpack.js",
```

*Note that you need to use appropriate loaders to pack everything in one file. e.g. `base64-image-loader` instead of `file-loader`*

Comment: So is it the case that the library images can only be used if they are inlined?

Comment: @davesaus you can keep images in separated files. It depends on how are you going to use it then

Comment: What i need if i want App also to build with lib together?

Comment: How do I get `import filename from "package/filename"`? and not `import {filename} from ...` by using this syntax?

Answer (score 6):

The comment written by @OlegPro is very helpful. I suggest every one to read this article for explanation of how these stuff work

http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/javascript-library-starter-using-webpack-es6

You need the following for sure if you want to be able to import the bundle file in your project

```
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, myLibrary),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    library: "myLibrary",   // Important
    libraryTarget: 'umd',   // Important
    umdNamedDefine: true   // Important
  },
```